# Label align location for input box

Tags: forms, input, labels, alignment

I have form with long input list and corresponding labels for them. Labels inserted in left, because form has a lot of input elements and right side is reserved for errors info. So I have only option to put label to the left from input box. (I cannot put labels to the top) So currently I am thinking how I should align labels for input box. I have two option:

a. *Right alignment*

> [image]

b. *Left alignment*

> [image]

So, what aproach is good in this particular case and why? Thank you for answers.

Comment: In-depth analysis of the [Label Placement in Forms](http://www.uxmatters.com/mt/archives/2006/07/label-placement-in-forms.php)

Answer (score 3):

From http://www.uxmatters.com/mt/archives/2006/07/label-placement-in-forms.php:

"**Label position**—Placing a label above an input field works better in most cases, because users aren’t forced to look separately at the label and the input field. Be careful to visually separate the label for the next input field from the previous input field.

**Alignment of labels**—In most cases, when placing labels to the left of input fields, using left-aligned labels imposes a heavy cognitive workload on users. Placing labels above input fields is preferable, but if you choose to place them to the left of input fields, at least make them right aligned."